# Remove Unicode Character in a String (JS)

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I have this piece of HTML code:`

```
<span class="raidListSlotCount">‭77‬/‭100‬</span>
```

equivalent to this, that is shown when I inspect the page:

```html
<span class="raidListSlotCount">&#8237;77&#8236;/&#8237;100&#8236;</span>
```

So, i can get that string which contains the 77/100 value with the following JS code: `var t = document.getElementsByClassName("raidListSlotCount")[3].innerHTML;`

but it turns out that it comes with another characters (UNICODE strong characters I assume) that shows up as "thrash" when displayed on console or when I split it with`t = t.split("/")` and then try to use `Number(t[0]), it returns NaN.`

Could you help me to find out an idea to remove these carachters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a regular expression `match` for numbers instead:

```js
const [num1, num2] = document.querySelector('span').textContent.match(/\d+/g)
console.log(num1, num2);
```

```html
<span class="raidListSlotCount">&#8237;77&#8236;/&#8237;100&#8236;</span>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't use entirely your code because the queryselector('span') returned another span number in the page BUT, i found out to this working code:
Number(document.getElementsByClassName("raidListSlotCount")[3].innerHTML.match(/\d+/g)[0])
Thank you !